# Could anyone tell better way to replace a line in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Current chef recipe Code

```
ruby_block 'replace_line' do
  block do
    file = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new(common_conf)
    file.search_file_replace_line(/fs.type.*/, 'fs.type='+fs_type)
    file.write_file
  end
  only_if { File.exist?(common_conf) }
end
```

I get following warning:

```
 Running handlers complete
 [0m[2017-09-01T03:22:36-05:00] INFO: Report handlers complete

Deprecated features used!
 Cloning resource attributes for ruby_block[replace_line] from prior resource
[0mPrevious ruby_block[replace_line]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/spark_deployer/recipes/execution_component.rb:61:in `from_file'
 [0mCurrent  ruby_block[replace_line]: /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/spark_deployer/recipes/execution_component.rb:70:in `from_file' at 1 location:[0m
     - /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/spark_deployer/recipes/execution_component.rb:70:in `from_file'[0m
   See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html for further details
```

Could anyone help me to write the above code in better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to

> See https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html for further details

as you were clearly told by the error message? If you have, you likely saw that prior to this recipe you have another one named exactly the same: `'replace_line'`. To fix the issue, you are to rename this recipe (and possibly all references to it,) to something unique, like, say:

```
ruby_block 'replace_line_fs_type' do
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're asking about a 'better way,' you might check out the [`line` cookbook](https://github.com/sous-chefs/line-cookbook). It provides a few primitives for editing lines, such as:

```
append_if_no_line "make sure a line is in some file" do
  path "/some/file"
  line "HI THERE I AM STRING"
end
```

The **best** solution would be to manage this whole file in Chef, and either embed a template in your cookbook, copy a file out of your cookbook, or write the entire file as part of your `ruby_block`. Partially managed files can be fraught with peril.

*Additionally, like [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45996175/70665) says, you're relying on resource cloning because you have multiple resources of the same name. Even if you switch to the line cookbook, you should also make sure all of your resource names are unique (or combine all the edits into a single resource).*

Comment: Just a note for the future, as of Chef 13 resource cloning is no longer a thing and so the warnings are gone.